# Not able create GEF instances in RCP view

Tags: eclipse-rcp

This is regarding an automation I need to use GEF in RCP application.

In one of the view I have to create an instance of GEF, but if I try to create those instances, it throws error saying could not instantiate view.

Here is the error dump

```
SESSION 2010-12-03 14:06:06.650 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0-ea
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product GEFTutorial.product
Command-line arguments:  -product GEFTutorial.product -data C:\Documents and Settings\rtiragat\workspace/../runtime-GEFTutorial.product -dev file:C:/Documents and Settings/rtiragat/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/GEFTutorial.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2010-12-03 14:06:09.680
!MESSAGE Unable to create view ID GEFTutorial.view: Plug-in "GEFTutorial" was unable to instantiate class "geftutorial.View".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/gef/EditPartFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ViewDescriptor.createView(ViewDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewPane.setVisible(ViewPane.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.createControl(PartSashContainer.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveHelper.activate(PerspectiveHelper.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.onActivate(Perspective.java:981)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.onActivate(WorkbenchPage.java:2632)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$27.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2986)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setActivePage(WorkbenchWindow.java:2967)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyOpenPage(WorkbenchWindow.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$23.runWithException(Workbench.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at geftutorial.Application.start(Application.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.gef.EditPartFactory
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 66 more
```

Comment: Did you manage to find the error?

Comment: no i wasn't able to find the error. i am struck. my idea after looking at the dump is " i would have imported a gef jar file that doesn't contain the definition for EditPartFactory class" any comments on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out the "[Shape diagram Editor](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-diagram-editor/shape.html)" and the wiki "[GEF_Description2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF_Description2)" page to check if your usage of a viewer is appropriate here.

See for instance [this example](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.gef/msg15959.html).

Comment: no i wasn't able to find the error. i am struck. my idea after looking at the dump is " i would have imported a gef jar file that doesn't contain the definition for EditPartFactory class" any comments on this

Comment: @Ravi: well, first: do you have the plugin GEF installed in your Eclipse?

Comment: yes i have it.if its not their then it would throw compile error when i try to  import gef package

Comment: @VonC -v3.6.1 is installed i rechecked it again

Comment: @Ravi: I don't see that class `EditPartFactory` in recent GEF edition (http://www.docjar.com/docs2web/s.jsp?q=EditPartFactory&t=j&start=0). Maybe it has been moved elsewhere?

Comment: @Ravi: I need to search for this class. I will keep you posted. Can you tell me where your GEFTutorial comes from?

Comment: @Vonc-Thanks a lot for u r interest .if u can give u r mail id i can send my source code and GEF tutorial.i have checked in my gef jar file   those classes(rooteditpart,EditPartFactory) are included but when i tried to open those files it shows "source not attached"

Comment: @Ravi: no luck so far. I will have to keep on looking for that class.

Comment: @VonC hi, now i am able to create my own graphical editor using GMF.but now i want to produce code with my graphical editor

Comment: @Ravi: excellent, did you find that class I didn't see initially? As for producing code, maybe a open source project like WindowsBuilder can give you good examples: http://code.google.com/javadevtools/eclipse-donation-faq.html